# $\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos(x)e^{i (a \cos(x) + b \cos^2(x)} dx$ and $\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos^2(x)e^{i (a \cos(x) + b \cos^2(x)} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I am currently dealing with the two integrals in the title and I want to find out, when their real part of their imaginary part vanishes ( so for which constellation of $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\}$ does this happen). 
I don't want to use numerical methods, so analytic results or symmetry consideration would be highly appreciated.
Again, the integrals are
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos(x)e^{i (a \cos(x) + b \cos^2(x))} dx$$
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos^2(x)e^{i (a \cos(x) + b \cos^2(x))} dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By splitting the integration interval in four equal parts we have:
$$ I_1 = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(x)\,e^{i(a\cos x+b\cos^2 x)}\,dx = 4i\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos x\sin\left(a\cos x+b\cos^2 x\right)\,dx,$$
$$ I_2 = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(x)^2\,e^{i(a\cos x+b\cos^2 x)}\,dx = 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^2(x) \cos\left(a\cos x+b\cos^2 x\right)\,dx$$
hence $I_1$ is always a pure imaginary number and $I_2$ is always a real number.

Bessel and Struve functions are useful tools to evaluate such integrals.